# Plotting log n time complexity in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, time-complexity, visualization

I am currently working on a project to plot the time it takes for different algorithms to run as a function of input size using Python and matplotlib. However, I am struggling to plot the time complexity of an O(log n) algorithm.

Here is the first version of the code that I am using (updated version is below):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def run_algo(n, func):
    start_time = time.time()  # current time
    func(n)
    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time - start_time

def linear(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i

def quadratic(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            j

def quadratic2(n):
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(i): 
            j

def cubic(n):
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n): 
            for k in range(n): 
                k

def log_n(n):
    low = 1
    high = n
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if mid * mid == n:
            return mid
        elif mid * mid < n:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    
    return -1

numberOfPoints = [60, 60, 60, 60, 1000]
min_value = [500, 50, 50, 10, 10**50]
max_value = [100000, 1000, 1000, 100, 10**101]
list_of_functions_to_run = [linear, quadratic, quadratic2, cubic, log_n]
titles = ["O(n)", "O(n^2)", "O(n^2)", "O(n^3)", "O(log n)"]
degrees = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]

for i, func in enumerate(list_of_functions_to_run):
    time_complexity = []
    n_values = np.linspace(min_value[i], max_value[i], numberOfPoints[i])
    for n in n_values:
        time_complexity.append(run_algo(int(n), func))
    # Smooth out the time complexity curve using a moving average
    window_size = 4
    moving_average = np.convolve(time_complexity, np.ones(window_size)/window_size, mode='valid')
    # Plot the time complexity curve and the smoothed curve
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(n_values[len(n_values)-len(moving_average):], moving_average, label='Smoothed')
    # Find a polynomial fit 
    x_values_for_fit = n_values[len(n_values)-len(moving_average):]
    label='Polynomial Fit'
    if titles[i] == "O(log n)":
        x_values_for_fit = np.log(x_values_for_fit)
        label='Logarithmic Fit'
    polyfit = np.polyfit(x_values_for_fit, moving_average, deg=degrees[i])
    polyfit_fn = np.poly1d(polyfit)
    plt.plot(n_values, polyfit_fn(n_values), label=label,color='tab:blue', linestyle='--')
    # Set the title and axis labels
    plt.title(f"Time Complexity: {titles[i]}")
    plt.xlabel("Input Size (n)")
    plt.ylabel("Time Complexity")
    plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The code runs without any errors and plots the graph of the time complexity of O(log n). However, the graph is not as expected, [it's a flat line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6v51.png). The [rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ila26.png) [of the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sycf5.png) [complexities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jglSB.png) are fine.

I tried to change multiple times the number of n values, the maximum n value, and the minimum n value but to no avail.

Can someone help me with this issue? How can I correctly plot the time complexity of O(log n) in Python using matplotlib?

Thank you in advance.

Update: I've replaced polyfit with scipy's curve_fit

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def run_algo(n, func):
    start_time = time.time()  # current time
    func(n)
    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time - start_time

def linear(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i

def quadratic(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            j

def quadratic2(n):
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(i): 
            j

def cubic(n):
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n): 
            for k in range(n): 
                k

def log_n(n):
    low = 1
    high = n
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if mid * mid == n:
            return mid
        elif mid * mid < n:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    
    return -1
    
def log_function(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x) + b

def polynom_function(x, a, b, n):
    return a *x**n + b

def linear_func(x, a, b):
    return polynom_function(x, a, b,1)

def quadratic_func(x, a, b):
    return polynom_function(x, a, b,2)

def cubic_func(x, a, b):
    return polynom_function(x, a, b,3)


numberOfPoints = [60, 60, 60, 60, 6000]
min_value = [500, 50, 50, 10, 2]
max_value = [100000, 1000, 1000, 100, 100]
list_of_functions_to_run = [linear, quadratic, quadratic2, cubic, log_n]
list_of_functions_to_fit = [linear_func, quadratic_func, quadratic_func, cubic_func, log_function]
titles = ["O(n)", "O(n^2)", "O(n^2)", "O(n^3)", "O(log n)"]

for i, func in enumerate(list_of_functions_to_run):
    time_complexity = []
    n_values = np.linspace(min_value[i], max_value[i], numberOfPoints[i])
    for n in n_values:
        time_complexity.append(run_algo(int(n), func))
    # Smooth out the time complexity curve using a moving average
    window_size = 4
    moving_average = np.convolve(time_complexity, np.ones(window_size)/window_size, mode='valid')
    # Plot the time complexity curve and the smoothed curve
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(n_values[len(n_values)-len(moving_average):], moving_average, label='Smoothed')
    # Find a curve fit 
    x_values_for_fit = n_values[len(n_values)-len(moving_average):]
    y_values_for_fit = moving_average
    func_to_fit = list_of_functions_to_fit[i]
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_to_fit, x_values_for_fit, y_values_for_fit)
    y_fit = func_to_fit(x_values_for_fit, *popt)
    plt.plot(x_values_for_fit, y_fit, label='fit: a=%f, b=%f' % tuple(popt), color='tab:blue', linestyle='--')
    # Set the title and axis labels
    plt.title(f"Time Complexity: {titles[i]}")
    plt.xlabel("Input Size (n)")
    plt.ylabel("Time Complexity")
    plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

But there's still [weird spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prbgB.png)

Comment: It's weird that you are using poly fit for the log case. If you want to fit using a straight line, then it need to be over log values. But the x-values are linearly spaced out, instead of log-spaced out. Also, the plot should then be log-log plot. and then you should see the straight line appear I think

Comment: The reason you're seeing a flatline is because log is flat. Your x-values go up to 1e101, which means 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. Over these values, log is mostly constant. log grows very fast, from 0 to 328, over the 1% leftmost x-values; and then log only grows from 328 to 335 for the remaining 99% values

Comment: See also: [this mathoverflow answer about the flat graph of logarithm](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377785)

Comment: Also look at the values on your y-axis: they go up to 1e95, which is 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. But log is pretty small; it only goes up to 335 in the range corresponding to the x-values. So log is squashed down, almost 0 in comparison to the huge range of your y-values.

Comment: @FlorentMonin You're right, I've replaced now polyfit with curve_fit. This can the fitted function is now logarithmic.

Comment: @Stef Yes I thought about it wrong. I tried now lower values and more points but now I get spikes instead of flat line.